# How to execute unit tests for octobercms/library

Tags: php, unit-testing, octobercms

What is the proper way of executing unit tests for [octobercms/library](https://github.com/octobercms/library)?

I could successfully execute unit tests with the following condition.

- Use the copy installed in my OctoberCMS project in vendor directory.
- Modify `bootstrap` path in october/rain/tests/phpunit.xml to `bootstrap="../../../../vendor/autoload.php"`
- Execute `../../../../vendor/bin/phpunit` from october/rain/tests.

But, I feel like there is a better way. I wonder how other committer is executing tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all thanks for showing interest in contributing to October CMS,

I would say you don't need to modify a single line.

first let's be specific and we only need to test `octobercms/library` as we don't need to make things complex

> let's assume you have working local October CMS based website on your machine.

1. now go to `vendor\october\rain` folder as `october lib` resides there. **(inside termial)**
2. now do `composer install` there

> **if you find any dependency issue in installation.(Then ONLY follow this)**, I found some problem here some dependency issue so, i need to remove this 2 dependencies from `composer.json`
>
> if you find same issue then : go to  "require-dev" section -> remove
>
> **1.**"illuminate/routing": "5.5.*"
>
> **2.**"swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "~5.1"
>
> **3.** now try to install `composer install` again.

3. when its done.
4. just got `vendor\october\rain\tests` directory **(inside termial)**
5. execute command **for windows `.\..\vendor\bin\phpunit.bat`** **and for linux/mac `./../vendor/bin/phpunit`**
6. it will automatically detect all the stuff and execute tests for you.

if you face any issue please add comment.

> https://github.com/octobercms/library/wiki/How-To-Use-Unit-Tests-%3F

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks so much for detailed explanation! Why don't you commit this in README? It will motivate more committers to write tests, I guess. Or, shall I?

Comment: Sure why not i will add it to read-me file, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: added it to proper place on its wiki, updated answer., thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Thanks! Just a nitpick, the URL in your answer is a bit wrong. I couldn't fix it coz it was less than 6 chars.